SCOPE_IDENTITY() is returning NULL instead of IDENTITY value - T-SQL
I'm using dynamic SQL to insert a default value into a table and want to return the SCOPE_IDENTITY() value for my surrogate key. However, SCOPE_IDENTITY() is returning NULL for some reason. Am I missing something?
Thanks!
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @SurrogateKey INT,
        @SchemaName VARCHAR(128) = 'dim',
        @TableName VARCHAR(128) = 'Sales',
        @NaturalKeyColumn VARCHAR(128) = 'SalesID',
        @NaturalKeyValue VARCHAR(40) = '100',
        @SurrogateKeyColumn VARCHAR(128) = 'SalesKey';

SET @SQL = N'SELECT @SurrogateKey = ' + QUOTENAME(@SurrogateKeyColumn) + 
           ' FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@SchemaName) + '.' + QUOTENAME(@TableName) + 
           ' WHERE ' + QUOTENAME(@NaturalKeyColumn) + ' = @NaturalKeyValue';

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL, N'@SurrogateKey INT OUTPUT, @NaturalKeyValue VARCHAR(40)', @SurrogateKey OUTPUT, @NaturalKeyValue;

IF @SurrogateKey IS NULL
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRANSACTION;

    SET @SQL = N'INSERT INTO ' + QUOTENAME(@SchemaName) + '.' + QUOTENAME(@TableName) + 
               ' (' + QUOTENAME(@NaturalKeyColumn) + ', InferredFlag)
                VALUES (@NaturalKeyValue, 1)';

    EXEC sp_executesql @SQL, N'@NaturalKeyValue VARCHAR(40)', @NaturalKeyValue;

    -- Check if the INSERT was successful
    IF @@ROWCOUNT > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @SQL = N'SELECT @SurrogateKey = SCOPE_IDENTITY()';

        EXEC sp_executesql @SQL, N'@SurrogateKey INT OUTPUT', @SurrogateKey OUTPUT;
    END

    COMMIT TRANSACTION;
END

SELECT @SurrogateKey;


Of course it does; you're asking for it in a different scope. If you INSERT data in one scope then use IDENTITY_SCOPE in a different scope isn't going to give you a value.

SCOPE_IDENTITY() unsurprisingly only works within a single scope. You need to create and execute a single dynamic SQL batch. This is also much more efficient.
Other issues with your code:

The transaction is being started in the wrong place, it needs to be before the SELECT.
You need to add locking hints to the SELECT, otherwise a shared lock is taken which won't help you. You need SERIALIZABLE and UPDLOCK here.
Object and column names should be stored in sysname variables, which is an alias for nvarchar(128).
XACT_ABORT ON should be used so that rollbacks happen correctly in case of errors.
You can SELECT directly out of dynamic SQL, you don't need the OUT parameter unless you need the value afterwards in the static side.

DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @SchemaName sysname = 'dim',
        @TableName sysname = 'Sales',
        @NaturalKeyColumn sysname = 'SalesID',
        @NaturalKeyValue VARCHAR(40) = '100',
        @SurrogateKeyColumn sysname = 'SalesKey';

SET @SQL = N'
DECLARE @SurrogateKey INT;

SET XACT_ABORT, NOCOUNT ON;

BEGIN TRAN;

SELECT @SurrogateKey = ' + QUOTENAME(@SurrogateKeyColumn) + '
FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@SchemaName) + '.' + QUOTENAME(@TableName) + ' WITH (SERIALIZABLE, UPDLOCK)
WHERE ' + QUOTENAME(@NaturalKeyColumn) + ' = @NaturalKeyValue;

IF @SurrogateKey IS NULL
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO ' + QUOTENAME(@SchemaName) + '.' + QUOTENAME(@TableName) + ' (' + QUOTENAME(@NaturalKeyColumn) + ', InferredFlag)
    VALUES (@NaturalKeyValue, 1);

    SET @SurrogateKey = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
END;

COMMIT;

SELECT @SurrogateKey;
';

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL,
  N'@NaturalKeyValue VARCHAR(40)',
    @NaturalKeyValue = @NaturalKeyValue;

